# Matlab's Tab completion for classes

Tags: java, matlab, class, path

I have the following project on my hands, and I am banging my head to the wall for this "little" caveat.

In the project Matlab [classes](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/object-oriented-programming-in-matlab.html) are used. Due to the structure of the project, I have the folders structured as follows:

```
+a/+b/+c/
```

Then, on `c` there are a bunch of other subfolders declared:

```
+a/+b/+c/+d
+a/+b/+c/+e
+a/+b/+c/+f
+a/+b/+c/+g
```

On one of those folders (let's sat `+e`) is where I am implementing my `.m` classes, which contain [`properties`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/properties-storing-data-and-state.html), as well as `Static` [`methods`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/methods-defining-operations.html):

```
+a/+b/+c/+e/my_class_1.m
+a/+b/+c/+e/my_class_2.m
+a/+b/+c/+e/my_class_3.m
+a/+b/+c/+e/my_class_4.m
```

---

So let's take a look into my `startup.m` file:

```
% add the path to the class
addpath(genpath('<previous_path_to_a>'));
% import the module
import a.b.c.e.*
```

What I would like to do now is to be able to press `my_class_1.` + <kbd>Tab</kbd> on the Matlab prompt and be shown the `properties` and `methods` available for that given class.

I know I could just use Matlab's [`methods()`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/methods.html) function for this, or the [`properties()`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/properties.html) one, but it would be really nice to be able to just type:

`help my_class_1.` + <kbd>Tab</kbd>

to be able to select the given `method` and see it's documentation.
Otherwise I have, as I said, to call [`methods()`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/methods.html) first to see what the names of the class's own `methods` are for this particular class, to be able to access its documentation.

---

**Edit:**

Of course, what does work is typing the whole path, in my example:

`help a.b.c.e.my_class_1.` + <kbd>Tab</kbd>

The question is how to get rid off those previously annoying `a.b.c.e.`

Comment: Is `e` a package or a class? You talk about a folder `+e`, indicating that it's a package, but you also talk about typing `e.` + tab to see the methods/properties of `e`, which would indicate that it's a class.

Comment: @SamRoberts sorry about the confusion, will fix the mistake now!

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, looks like you're right. Tab completion of methods and properties only seems to work with fully qualified class names, even if the class is on the path and imported.

I don't know of a workaround. If I were you, I'd enter an enhancement request with MathWorks for that. It would seem like an obvious and nice thing to have.

Comment: I have written a service request on Mathworks' page. But yes, it seems to be not so trivial without their assistance :(